# What is the proper way of using RMI remote objects on the client side?

Tags: java, rmi

In a dialog (window) let suppose we have some buttons and when a button is pressed a remote method invocation take place.

How it is better:

- create the remote object (registry.lookup()) one time and use this object every time we need a remote method invocation?
- each time we need a remote method invocation we execute registry.lookup() and after this we call the remote method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do your lookup once, and cache the reference to the remote object somewhere. The rmiregistry is just used for bootstrapping. Doing a lookup every time will cause lots of unnecessary network calls.

The [ServiceLocator](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/ServiceLocator.html) pattern talks about it:

> The Service Locator pattern centralizes distributed service object
>   lookups, provides a centralized point of control, and may act as a
>   cache that eliminates redundant lookups.